# how to take input from the keyboard without asking the number of input he want to enter

Tags: java, input, keyboard

I have tried to code in which the code stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers.In this code the user is asked to give the number of input he wants to give.But I am not getting how to  take input without asking the user how many number he wants to enter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class antarahac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pattern[] = new int[1];
        pattern[0] = 42;
        int max, ls, lp = 1;
        System.out.println("enter the no. of values you want to enter");
        ls = sc.nextInt();
        int input[] = new int[ls];
        for (int i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
            input[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }
        max = ls - lp - 1;
        boolean flag;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            flag = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < lp && flag == true; j++) {
                if (pattern[j] != input[j + i]) {
                    flag = false;
                    System.out.println("" + input[i]);

                }
            }
            if (flag == true) {

                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: while (! input.equals("endInput")) for instance. if ( flag == true ) can be rewritten as if ( flag ) (less likely to contain type errors

Comment: `int input; while((input = sc.nextInt()) != 42)` but you will need to declare an array without knowing the size or learn to use a `List`. PS: why do you use arrays of 1 cell for `pattern` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a loop until the value you want is acquired. You mention to stop when the user input `42` :

```
int tmp;
while((tmp = sc.nextInt()) != 42){
    // do something
}
```

This will read input until a `42` is inputted.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int tmp;
while((tmp = sc.nextInt()) != 42){
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
sc.close();
```

Input :

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 48, 42

Output:

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 48

## More information

Now, if you want to store those, if you use an array, you will need to create an array with enough spaces (risky) like : `new int[1000];` or you can use a `List` to use a dynamic sized collection. If you don't know it, simply know that to create a `List` you just need to :

```
List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>(); //int[] input = new int[####];
```

Then to add a value at the end you can :

```
input.add(i); //input[index] = i;
```

And to read the value (get) :

```
input.get(index);  // input[index]
```

Then, I notice you use `ls`, previous the size of the array, you can know how many values were added in the list using the method `size()` :

```
ls = input.size();
```